# program only in valgrind run without stoppage

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

My program (it is an smtp server program, tested by jmeter) run without any problem when it is run by valgrind.
But failed (got SIGABRT) finally, if it is running without valgrind or run within 'gdb' debugger.

I've tested all of the valgrind's tools (memcheck,helgrind,drd,massif) but no one reported any problem. I haven't found any memory leaks (checked by mtrace() ).

I've got the following :

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0xb7101b70 (LWP 1639)]
0xb776d416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

the backtrace show various locations which changend run by run. The problems always allude to malloc() or free() (and always correlate with a string (char array) )

The question is: how can I found the problem, if valgrind and mtrace did not show any problem and the program can run without stoppage  (within valgrind) in an endless jmeter test loop?